# SkiaSharp SKBitmap.Decode() Value cannot be null. (Parameter 'buffer')

Tags: c#, .net-6.0, blazor-server-side, memorystream, skiasharp

I am trying to upload multiple images from a Blazor InputFile component:

```
<InputFile OnChange="@LoadFiles" multiple accept=".png, .jpg, .jpeg, .gif" />
```

Once in memory, using SkiaSharp I need to resize them down to a maximum of 1000 pixels wide/high.  I created a helper method for this, but it seems to fail on any image that is over approximately 4MB.  I have pieced the following logic together from searches plus whatever (rather lacking) Microsoft documentation is available, so my approach may be entirely wrong:

```
using SkiaSharp;

public static byte[] Resize(byte[] fileContents, int maxWidth, int maxHeight)
{
    using MemoryStream ms = new(fileContents);
    using SKBitmap sourceBitmap = SKBitmap.Decode(ms); // <-- EXCEPTION HERE ON LARGER FILES
                        
    int height = Math.Min(maxHeight, sourceBitmap.Height);
    int width = Math.Min(maxWidth, sourceBitmap.Width);
    var quality = SKFilterQuality.High;

    using SKBitmap scaledBitmap = sourceBitmap.Resize(new SKImageInfo(width, height), quality);
    using SKImage scaledImage = SKImage.FromBitmap(scaledBitmap);
    using SKData data = scaledImage.Encode();

    return data.ToArray();
}
```

In the Razor component:

```
foreach (var file in e.GetMultipleFiles(maxAllowedFiles))
{
    // Convert uploaded file into a byte array

    await using var memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
    await file.OpenReadStream(maxFileSizeBytes).CopyToAsync(memoryStream);
    var imageByteArray = memoryStream.ToArray();
    await memoryStream.DisposeAsync();

    // Use byte array to generate a resized image

    var resizedFullSizeBytes = EventFinderShared.Images.ImageDimensionCalculation.Resize(imageByteArray, maxWidthOrHeight, maxWidthOrHeight); // <== Error here
    var resizedThumbnailBytes = EventFinderShared.Images.ImageDimensionCalculation.Resize(imageByteArray, thumbnailWidthOrHeight, thumbnailWidthOrHeight);

    // Further usage removed for brevity...
}
```

Using the debugger, `byte[] fileContents` definitely is not null, so I have no idea what's occurring.

```
System.ArgumentNullException
  HResult=0x80004003
  Message=Value cannot be null. Arg_ParamName_Name
  Source=SkiaSharp
  StackTrace:
   at SkiaSharp.SKManagedStream.OnReadManagedStream(IntPtr buffer, IntPtr size)
   at SkiaSharp.SKAbstractManagedStream.ReadInternal(IntPtr s, Void* context, Void* buffer, IntPtr size)
   at SkiaSharp.SkiaApi.sk_codec_new_from_stream(IntPtr stream, SKCodecResult* result)
   at SkiaSharp.SKCodec.Create(SKStream stream, SKCodecResult& result)
   at SkiaSharp.SKBitmap.Decode(Stream stream)
   at EventFinderShared.Images.ImageDimensionCalculation.Resize(Byte[] fileContents...
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The issue was due to a [bug in SkiaSharp](https://github.com/mono/SkiaSharp/pull/2265) 2.88.2.  Updating to 2.88.3 has solved the problem, although it appears that related issues may still exist.